# Visual Studio 2017 download location

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Where does visual studio 2017 download its packages to when you install?

It would be nice if i could make a backup of the downloaded packages.

Reason for asking, is i already installed it on one PC, and would like to grab those "already downloaded" files and install it on another pc.

I understand that i could specify a download path, or make an "offline" installer, however, i did not know this beforehand, and would like to know the default location of packages being downloaded when using the web installer

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: @JanDvorak please read the question before making comments and downvoting

Comment: Ah, sorry, i misread.

Comment: You might want to edit the title to prevent this sort of confusion

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Visual Studio 2017 on multiple computers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42695324/installing-visual-studio-2017-on-multiple-computers)

Comment: @SteffenWinkler, not entirely.. i already instaslled it ona  pc, My question releates to the packages already downloaded

Comment: ah, okay. Yeah that's a different question now - particulary about the 're-use already installed things'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe, you can look at the following referrences:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-an-offline-installation-of-visual-studio

https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToMakeAnOfflineInstallerForVS2017.aspx

Comment: Thanx, I created an offline installer using hanselman's method.

Answer (score 9):

on my machine, the location is here:

C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\

Comment: In my case (VS 2017 Community), it is located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\

Answer (score 2):

Run the "Visual Studio Installer" again and notice there are four tabs:

1. Workloads (the default)
2. Individual components
3. Language packs
4. **Installation locations**

Click on that fourth tab "Installation locations" then the second textbox on that screen "Download cache" has the download location, by default it is

`C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages`

Comment: I'm installing VS 2022 Community and it is still the same cache location.

Answer (score 2):

> in november/2019, windows 7 SP1, 32 bits
> the download folder for Visual Studio 2019 Comunity is:
> **C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio**
> It contains 3 folders, named: 2019, COMMON and Installer
>
> there is other one:
> **C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages**
> but here, only appear some *.json files