# Installing Visual Studio 2017 on multiple computers

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

How can I install visual studio on multiple computers without downloading multiple component of visual studio that is upto 20gb or more on each computer. Is there any way of downloadimg everything once and installing on all the computers.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-an-offline-installation-of-visual-studio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the layout switch and optionally add the workloads or package ids you want to store in your local cache. [The docs are outlined here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/use-command-line-parameters-to-install-visual-studio).

```
vs_setup --layout c:\vssetup --all
```

Comment: Note: if you don't filter what you include (command line options are in the docs) you'll get a ~50GB download. It might be easier to download for each install...